# Why are there 2 spots in my TLC of furan?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, chromatography

I'm working on a monoalkylation of furan, and I'm trying to separate my product from byproducts. When comparing the TLC (10% EtOAc in hexane) of my mixture with that of furan (starting material), I observe 2 spots, one at the bottom line and one around rf~0.8.
Any clue of what this can be?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to test each of these two spots with appropriate reagents. Are they alcohols, ketones, aldehydes, etc, ?

Comment: Does the lower spot move off the baseline if you increase the polarity of the eluent?

Comment: I suspect your product is the high running spot. What you may have is a small amount of polyfuran that has a very strong UV chromophore and is sitting on the baseline

Comment: When comparing the TLC of your mixture with that of furan as you say – where is the sport of furan?